# In Godfather I and/or The Godfather Saga, who played the child star of Woltz?

Tags: the-godfather

In the book and Saga it is made clear that Woltz is molesting his juvenile star named "Janie." We see her in two scenes: Right before Hagen meets Woltz for the first time, they are having a party for the kid and then in Woltz's mansion Tom sees the distraught-looking child who is swiftly taken back into her room by her mother who is not concerned about the molestation presumably as long as the kid gets roles. Later in Saga, Hagen tells Vito about this and Vito refers to it as an "infamnia."

Now I am not sure she was in any scenes in Godfather I or if she was referred to in that scene back in New York; maybe it was just in Saga. But IMDB does not have anything about the child or the child's mother listed in either version of GF. My sense is that this is deliberate, the actress maybe did not want to be associated with the role.

In fact, I have the vaguest recollection, no idea from where, that Coppola is keeping it a secret. Many people are still around from the film but this info seems still to be a unavailable. I would be interested in confirmation that Coppola is in fact protecting someone who wished to remain anonymous or any other info. Tiny details about the films are known, but not this one.

Comment: Best I can find is a fragment of an answer on answers.com. The actress was supposedly Janet Kobelski.

Comment: <dbugger> I think I see the same fragment, hitting "more" does not tell us more. Interestingly/sadly the only Janet Kobelski that google brings up died in 1971 and was born in 1957. So the age would have been correct although she would have passed away before the movie was released. The mother is also not mentioned. I would sure like to know why this is so mysterious.

Comment: Could be if the actress and and the girl who died are one-in-the-same, that they decided not to include her in the credits.

Comment: Sure but this was her first and last movie. Find-a-grave has both her parents gone and even the very sad death of her infant older brother. The only explanation I can think of is that her folks decided this was not the way they wanted their daughter remembered. This kind of anonymity is poignant.

Comment: Need to talk to Coppola or find an AD or production assistant and see if more details can be unearthed.

Comment: I will do my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to dbugger we can see in answers.com (which is not perhaps the most easy-to-use website) that Janet Kobelski worked under the professional name of Janet Jordan and passed away from leukemia in 1971 at the age of 13 -- this was before Godfather was released. Assuming this information is correct, she is not listed in any other movies using either name. She went to St. Vincent Ferrer in Manhattan which may turn out to be a source of further information.